# Invariant affine subspaces: It's possible that $\dim(f(V))\neq\dim(V)$?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

I'm studying geometry right now. I saw that an affine subspace $V$ is invariant under $\ f\ $ if $\ f(V)\subset V$. After reading that, I wondered this:

Is it possible that $\dim(f(V))\neq\dim(V)$?

That is: Could be $V=P+\langle\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2}\rangle$  an invariant affine subspace and $f(V)=Q+\langle\vec{v_1}\rangle$? Or in other words, an invariant plane can be converted under $f$ in a line?

Comment: If $V=\mathbb{R}$ and $f=0$ then $\dim f(V) = 0, \dim V =1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

An example is an affine projection of a space (whatever its dimension) on a line.